# Joining and filtering one-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database, h2

I need some help about optimal structuring of SQL query. I have model like this:
[image: segment of database model]

I'm trying some kind of join between tables `NON_NATURAL_PERSON` and `NNP_NAME`. Because I have many names in table `NNP_NAME` for one person I can't do one-to-one `SELECT * from NON_NATURAL_PERSON inner join NNP_NAME` etc.  That way I'll get extra rows for every name one person has.

Data in tables:
[image: PERSON data] [image: NON_NATURAL_PERSON data] [image: NNP_NAME data]

How to extend this query to get rows marked red on picture shown below? My wannabe query criteria is: Always join name of typeA only if exists. If not, join name of typeB. If neither exists join name of typeC.

```
SELECT nnp.ID, name.NAME, name.TYPE 
FROM NON_NATURAL_PERSON nnp
INNER JOIN NNP_NAME name ON (name.NON_NATURAL_PERSON = nnp.ID)
```

[image: query result]

Comment: any particular reason why you tagged both `mysql` and `h2`?

Comment: @sstan No. I aimed universal SQL. My testing platforms are MySQL and H2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If type is spelled exactly as it's written (typeA, typeB, typeC) then you can use MIN() function:

```
SELECT NON_NATURAL_PERSON, MIN(type) AS min_type
FROM NNP_NAME
GROUP BY NON_NATURAL_PERSON
```

if you also want the username you can use this query:

```
SELECT
  n1.NON_NATURAL_PERSON AS ID,
  n1.Name,
  n1.Type
FROM
  NNP_NAME n1 LEFT JOIN NNP_NAME n2
  ON n1.NON_NATURAL_PERSON = n2.NON_NATURAL_PERSON
     AND n1.Type > n2.type
WHERE
  n2.type IS NULL
```

Please see this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e75eb/2). If Types are not literally sorted, change this line:

```
     AND n1.Type > n2.type
```

with this:

```
     AND FIELD(n1.Type, 'TypeA', 'TypeB', 'TypeC') >
         FIELD(n2.type, 'TypeA', 'TypeB', 'TypeC')
```

MySQL FIELD(str, str1, str2, ...) function returns the index (position) of str in the str1, str2, ... list, and 0 if str is not found. You want to get the "first" record, ordered by type, for every NON_NATURAL_PERSON. There are multiple ways to get this info, I chose a self join:

```
ON n1.NON_NATURAL_PERSON = n2.NON_NATURAL_PERSON
   AND n1.Type > n2.type -- or filed function
```

with the WHERE condition:

```
WHERE n2.type IS NULL
```

this will return all rows where the join didn't succeed - the join won't succeed when there is not n2.type that is less than n1.type - it will return the first record.

**Edit**

If you want a platform independent solution, avoiding the creation of new tables, you could use CASE WHEN, just change

```
AND n1.Type > n2.Type
```

with

```
AND
  CASE
    WHEN n1.Type='TypeA' THEN 1
    WHEN n1.Type='TypeB' THEN 2
    WHEN n1.Type='TypeC' THEN 3
  END
  >
  CASE
    WHEN n2.Type='TypeA' THEN 1
    WHEN n2.Type='TypeB' THEN 2
    WHEN n2.Type='TypeC' THEN 3
  END
```

Comment: Types are not literally sorted. It's exidentally like that, for test purposes

Comment: Thanks man. But, is there any other way than using mysql specific FIELD() function? Can you explain a little bit why are you using join of 2 same nnp_name tables?

Comment: @shx I've updated my answer, there are multiple ways to solve your problem, for example using GROUP_CONCAT ordered by type, and then getting the first element of the list... but a self join is the one I prefer.

Comment: You're the man. Thanks. Still that greater then > operator is bothering me. What if typeA become foo, typeB become bar, typeC become blahblah? Priorities between them will stay in the same order. Lexicographical order is not requirement.

Comment: @shx that's why I'm using FIELD function, so you can specify any custom order FIELD(type, 'bar', 'foo', 'bla', 'zzz', 'aaa'), so bar=1 foo=2 bla=3 zzz=4 aaa=5 - a more general SQL solution would require a table with types and their order

Comment: Is there any way to upgrade this with case/when/then logic?

Comment: @shx yes... you want a platform independent solution that just uses standard SQL? can you add a new table or do you prefer just CASE WHEN?

Comment: Yes. I want platform independent solution. I would like to avoid adding new table.

Answer (score 1):

There is a piece of information missing. You say:

```
Always join name of typeA only if exists. If not, join name of typeB. If neither exists join name of typeC.
```

But you do not indicate **why** you prefer typeA over typeB. This information is not included in your data. 
In the answer of @fthiella, either lexicographical is assumed, or an arbitrary order is given using `FIELD`. This is also the reason why two joins with the table `nnp_name` is necessary.

You can solve this problem by adding a table `name_type (id, name, order)` and changing the type column to contain the id. This will allow you to add the missing information in a clean way.

With an additional join with this new table, you will be able get the preferred nnp_name for each row.

Comment: You're right. Additional table would be the cleanest way but I don't have that option. I'll have to do some case/when/then logic because typeA could be FOO, typeB could be BAR etc.